# Print Empty String when DataBinder.Eval is NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, databinder

I have the following in my repeater:

```
<div class="LabelHolderrepeatershort" style="font-size:10px"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%></div>
        <div class="LabelHolderrepeatershort"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date", "{0:M/d/yy}")%></div>
        <div class="LabelHolderrepeater"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Hours")%></div>
        <div class="LabelHolderrepeater"  style="font-size:10px"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Note")%></div>
        <div class="LabelHolderrepeater"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DateSubmitted")%></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

How can I print an empty string when `Note` is `NULL` because the `DateSubmitted` div is being displayed where the `Note` div when `Note` is `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

you can use ternary operator, like this

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Note") != NULL ? "SomeValue" : "Some other value"
```